# Angular 2 set selected property

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am trying to set selected option in Angular2.

I have a select.

```
<select class="form-control" id="country"  [(ngModel)]="facility.country"  formControlName="countryField" (ngModelChange)="countrySelected($event)" >
     <option id="countryOption{{c.id}}" *ngFor="let c of rawCountries" [ngValue]="c">{{c.message}}</option>
</select>
```

And on select method.

```
countrySelected(): void {
   this.facility.country = this.rawCountries.find(rawCountries => rawCountries.name === this.facility.country.name);
}
```

I have registration in 2 steps, which are represented by 2 different components. This select is in the first step of registration. The user has an option to return back to the first step after he completes it. I have a problem to make the option he selected in the first step, once again selected. It changes back to the default option and my model with it.

I  tried this solution but it does not work.

```
<option id="countryOption{{c.id}}" [selected]="facility.country && (facility.country.id==c.id)" *ngFor="let c of rawCountries" [ngValue]="c">{{c.message}}</option>
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: `(ngModelChange)="countrySelected($event)` just does again what `[(ngModel)]="facility.country"` does already.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer Thank you for your reaction. I deleted ngModelChange.

Comment: Is it working now or still not working? I'm not sure I fully understand your question.

Comment: No it does not work. When I use router to switch back from the second component to the first one, than the input fields of type text are populated with the data, but the selects have default options instead of those that user picked chosed before.

Comment: You need to set `facility.country`(in code) to the user selected value when you navigate back. You need to store it somewhere (shared service or similar) to be able the get the value the user has chosen before.

Comment: I am storing it in the shared service. I dont know how to set the correct option in the DOM. I am asking how to do this [selected]="facility.country && (facility.country.id==c.id)".

Comment: You should not set it in the DOM. You should set it in `facility.country` in and `ngModel` will take it from there and make it the selected one.

Comment: Do you know about working example? I could not find any, that would work for me. There might be an issue that the list of countries is loaded via Promise from server and this might change the list of countries. The one which is stored in facility.country might not be in this new list.

Comment: Then you might need to update `facility.country` to a value that is in the new list or no element will be shown as selected.

Comment: That's the behaviour I am facing right now. I try your solution. I will make this switch in OnInit method. Anyway Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer You are right. I have to change it manually to an object from the new array of countries. The arrray of countries should not change though, but it does change. I dont call server to get the countries again and they are static. I am little bit puzzled why angular2?/javascipt? consider it as a new array. You can post  answer and I will accept. You really helped me. Thank you.

Comment: If the array is modified it has to be your code. Angular or the browser don't consider unchanged arrays being changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(ngModelChange)="countrySelected($event) just does again what [(ngModel)]="facility.country" does already.

You need to set `facility.country` (in code) to the user selected value when you navigate back. You need to store it somewhere (shared service or similar) to be able the get the value the user has chosen before.